# AsyncTask Does not work in SeekBarChangeListener

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm going to create a flash light program. it works with progress bar change as user input for setting sleep function value to Blinking flash light. wen i call my AsyncTask from SeekBarChangeListener it does not work and nothing happen. but when i call it from onCreate function or other classes, every thing is OK and work correctly.

My SeekBarChangeListener:

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Blinker bbb = new Blinker();

            seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            try {
                bbb.execute(progress*100);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("got interrupted!");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

My AsyncTask:

```
    public final class Blinker extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        try {
            while (isFlashing)
            {
                turnOffFlashing();
                Thread.sleep(params[0]);
                turnOnFlashing();
                Thread.sleep(params[0]);
                if (isCancelled()) break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

If you have any idea to make it works please share with me. Thank you.

Comment: What is your requirement? Any reason to calling Asynctask in onProgressChange

Comment: @PankajKumar I can not run while loop in the main threat. it will block the UI. for example if user decide to choose 10 as Sleep value, The Torch will flashes once every 10 seconds and User cannot cancel this process and change the sleep value.